# React Native not connecting to VS Code Debugger

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I've created a new React Native project -- using `react-native init myproject` and now trying to `debug` it in Visual Studio Code. When I click `Debug Android`, I get an error in Android emulator telling me that it can't connect to remote debugger -- see below:
[image]

In the Debug screen, I added the necessary config settings into `launch.json` -- see below.
[image]

What else do I need to do to be able to debug my React Native app in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and then reload or rebuild emulator by using `react-native run android`

Answer (score 1):

Try to:
1. Disable `Debug Android`
2. run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
3. Close `Chrome Debug remote`
4. Stop and run again `react-native start --reset-cache`, reload your app and wait app start and then try again `Debug Android`.

It works always with me